# TinyMCE move cursor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'd like to write a tinyMCE plugin that allows the nesting of sub and sup tags.

Right now I've written a command that inserts raw HTML '' at the cursor when you push the button / hit the shortcut keys. However, this will only work if I can then move the cursor to the middle of the new tag.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to move the cursor. There are some suggested hacks, but they are very hacky. This can't be that hard because, as I understand it, this is how the `[b]` and `[i]` buttons work too.

Is there a better way to be doing this? How can I write a tinyMCE function that puts the user in "sub mode" or "sup mode" and allows them to nest "sub" and "sup" modes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will set the cursor to the specified html element.

```
// sets the cursor to the specified element, ed ist the editor instance
// start defines if the cursor is to be set at the start or at the end
setCursor: function (ed, element, start) {

    var doc = ed.getDoc();
    if (typeof doc.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        range.collapse(start);
        var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
        var sel = win.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(element);
        textRange.collapse(start);
        textRange.select();
    }
},
```

In order to nest sups you need to make sure that sups and subs may be nested. Please check the [extended_valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/extended_valid_elements) and [valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/valid_elements) configuration parameter.
sub and sup may not be nested by default! You need to overwrite this part of the ruleset.

Comment: help please. This code don't work in Opera (11.10, 2092, Win32XP): Uncaught exception: [object DOMException] ... range.selectNodeContents(el);

Comment: i fear Opera is not fully supported by Tinymce. You might want to have a look at the newest tinymce beta source code - there is function built in that will set the cursor - maybe that one will work for your opera use case

Comment: I do not know what happened but after adding a few lines of code, all become well :)